# AttributeError: 'RDS' object has no attribute 'modify_db_snapshot_attribute'

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, amazon-rds

Following is the **Boto3(1.2.1)** Script for aws connection.

```
 conn = Boto3Connecton.get_rds_boto3_connection(region='us-east-1',arn=arn)

 response = conn.modify_db_snapshot_attribute(DBSnapshotIdentifier='rds-snap',
                                         AttributeName='restore',
                                         ValuesToAdd=[
                                             'XXXXXXXXXXX',
                                         ])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'RDS' object has no attribute 'modify_db_snapshot_attribute'
```

How to fix this?

Note: conn is a valid object,it is correctly showing the response for describe_db_instances() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is with the **botocore(0.109.0)** library.I upgrade the  **botocore(1.3.8)** library which is required in boto3 to the latest one and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

modify_db_snapshot_attribute() is available in Boto3 1.2.2
Upgrade your client and you should be good to go.